# Missing become password in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create playbook for deploy with simple scenario: login to server and clone/update open github repo.
All access parameters written in ~/.ssh/config

Here are my files:

1. hosts

   [staging]

   staging
2. deploy.yml

   ```
   - hosts: staging
     tasks:
     - name: Update code
     git: repo=https://github.com/travis-ci-examples/php.git dest=hello_ansible
   ```

   When I am trying to run `ansible-playbook -s deploy.yml -i hosts`, it outputs error like this:

> GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
>   fatal: [staging] => Missing become password
>
> TASK: [Update code] *********************************************************** 
>   FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting

I have tried to add `sudo: False` and `become: False`, but it does not seem to have any effect. I assume this operation should not request sudo password as I am trying work with files in ssh user's home directory.

I am sorry if my question is a bit lame, but I do not have much experience with Ansible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is asking for the sudo password because you are using the -s option. It seems like you do not want to use sudo for this task so try running the command without -s.

```
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i hosts
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I got this one from one of manuals assuming it is an argument for playbook file without even checking it.

Comment: @user2665732 use ansible-playbook --help, or ansible-doc, or visit docs.ansible.com for information about all the options at the commandline.